# if a subset in $C([0,1])$ is bounded and equicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness, equicontinuity

Let $F= \{ f \in C([0,1]) :  \int_0^1 |f(x)| dx \leq 1 \}$ then does $F$ bounded and equicontuous?

I am not sure how can I relate the function values with the integral of the function.

Comment: Are you asking if the set $F$ is bounded with respect to the supremum norm?

Comment: @CameronWilliams, yes, under the sup norm.

Comment: You know that $$f_n(x) = x^n$$ is not equicontinuous. How would you modify this?

Comment: Can you construct a sequence of positive functions that have integral $1$ but have norms increasing to infinity? Hint: consider a triangle that has height $2n$ and width $1/n$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams. I remember these functions, I constructed them their areas are 1, and they are not bounded, but are they not equicontinuous, correct?

Comment: @macton. how about $f_n(x)=(n+1)x^n$? it lives in $l^{\infinity}$ and not bounded, but how can I show it is not equicontinuous?

Comment: You show a set of functions is not equicontinuous by listing out an $\epsilon > 0$ so that for every $\delta > 0$, $$|f(x) - f(y)| \geq \epsilon$$ for some horrible choice of $x, y$ and $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$f_n(x)=(n+1)x^n$$

Notice that for $x \neq 1$,
$$
|f_n(1) - f_n(x)| = (n+1)(1 - x_0^n)
$$
and as $x^n \to 0$ for $x \neq 1$, we see that the difference $|f_n(1) - f_n(x)|$ will not be bounded as $n$ came large, therefore this family is not equicontinuous.